# Initialize a 2D matrix from mySQL recordset in Java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc

How can i initialize a 2-dimensional matrix from records coming from a database. I know how to do it in a for loop, but how should id o in such a situation:

```
Statement s = con.createStatement();
ResultSet res = s.executeQuery("my query");

while(res.next()){

   //Here i want to put records from  
   //2 colums say t1 and t2 in a 2D marix say result[][]            

}
```

While this is how i would fill the matrix:

```
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<result[i].length; j++){
          result[i][j] = value;
   }
}
```

I have no clue how to do this. Please suggest someting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the number of columns, then the solution would be

```
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   res.next();
   result[i][0] = res.getInt("field1");
   result[i][0] = res.getInt("field2");
   ...
}
```

if your columns are numbered, you can then use a second loop as per your code and do

```
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
   res.next();
   for(int j=0; j<numfields; j++) {
      result[i][j] = res.getInt("field"+j);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to increment the column number for "field2".

Comment: thanks but i figured out a simple while with if statements can also do the job. Here i need to be sure about tte size of records, else i will run into trouble.